# Saving datas from treeview to csv file tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello I wrote a program in tkinter (Python) and I have a problem with saving datas from treeview to file CSV. I dont use any sql database. Just problem with saving content of treeview. Does anybody please have any idea how to save content of treeview to CSV file according to my code?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from tkcalendar import Calendar,DateEntry
import csv
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo,askquestion
    root = Tk()
root.title("Medicine database")

one = StringVar()
two = StringVar()
three = StringVar()
four = StringVar()
    def quit():
    MsgBox = askquestion('Exit Application','Are you sure you want to exit the application',icon = 'warning')
    if MsgBox == 'yes':
        root.destroy()
def save():
    with open("new.csv","w",newline='') as f:
        w=csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
        w.writerow(tree.get_children())
        showinfo("Save to CSV file","File was saved")
def add_medicine():
    row = tree.insert("",END,values=(e0.get(),e1.get(),e2.get(),cal1.get()))
    e0.delete(0,END)
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e2.delete(0,END)
def select(event):
    try:
        cursor = tree.focus()
        content = tree.item(cursor)
        row = content["values"]
        one.set(row[0])
        two.set(row[1])
        three.set(row[2])
    except IndexError:
        pass
def delete_all():
    for i in tree.get_children():
        tree.delete(i)
def edit():
    try:
        x = tree.selection()[0]
        for item in x:
            tree.item(x,values=(e0.get(),e1.get(),e2.get(),cal1.get()))
    except IndexError:
        pass
def remove_item():
    selected_items = tree.selection()[0]
    tree.delete(selected_items)
def open_CSV():
    with open("new.csv") as myfile:
        csvread = csv.reader(myfile,delimiter=",")
        for i in csvread:
            print(i)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=25,selectmode=EXTENDED)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three","four")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=160)
tree.column("three",width=130)
tree.column("four",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ilość ampułek")
tree.heading("four",text="Data ważności")
tree["show"]="headings"
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you get error message or what ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should add some example data in code so we could run it and see problem. You could even reduce code - we don't need `select()`, `remove_item()`, `edit()` to save data. (PL: mógłbyś dodać przykładowe dane w kodzie abyśmy mogli to uruchomić i zobaczyć problem. Mógłbyś także zredukować kod - nie potrzebujemy `select()`, `remove_item()`, `edit()` aby zapisywać dane)

Comment: BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You could add empty line between your functions. And you could put all function before `root = Tk()` - this way code will be more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is minimal working code without not important functions, variables, modules but with some example data at start.

Main element is

```
        for row_id in tree.get_children():
            row = tree.item(row_id)['values']
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
import csv

# --- functions ----

def load_csv():
    with open("new.csv") as myfile:
        csvread = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',')
        
        for row in csvread:
            print('load row:', row)
            tree.insert("", 'end', values=row)

def save_csv():
    with open("new.csv", "w", newline='') as myfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',')
        
        for row_id in tree.get_children():
            row = tree.item(row_id)['values']
            print('save row:', row)
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, height=25, selectmode='extended')
tree.pack()

tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
tree.column("one",   width=120)
tree.column("two",   width=160)
tree.column("three", width=130)
tree.column("four",  width=160)
tree.heading("one",   text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two",   text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ilość ampułek")
tree.heading("four",  text="Data ważności")
tree["show"] = "headings"

button_load = tk.Button(root, text='Load', command=load_csv)
button_load.pack()
button_save = tk.Button(root, text='Save', command=save_csv)
button_save.pack()

# add some data for test
tree.insert("", 'end', values=[1, "A", "B", "C"])
tree.insert("", 'end', values=[2, "X", "Y", "Z"])
           
root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I also found another solution for loading CSV:

Comment: with open("new.csv") as myfile:
            csvread = csv.reader(myfile,delimiter=",")
            for i in csvread:
                tree.insert("",END,values=(i[0]))

Comment: but using `i[0]` you get only first column.

Comment: But when I load a csv file it loads to all four columns and all rows

Comment: maybe problem is that you use different delimiter then `,` and then it read row as one string and when it sends it as string `values="1,A,B,C"` then `tkinter` treats it as four aguments. But it can make problem when you will have text with `,` in one column - it can treats this `,` as column separator and split text from one column into two columns.

Comment: I changed delimiter to "\t"

Comment: you could check `print( i[0] )` to see what you get as first column from CSV. It could explain why it behave this way.

Comment: Yes it works great but thank you man for help but I also try another option for educational purposes. ;)