# Advice on how to store data

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, storing-data, data-entry

I am fairly new to coding and I am making an app in tkinter with a window that takes a series of user inputs(string&int). i need to be able to open this window multiple times and input different data and i need it to save it every time so I can display the information in seperate windows later on. i will include the code for the window. to be clear, i don't want to overwrite the data, i want it to save each set of data seperately. any help (code or advice) would be great :) thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

add = tk.Tk()
add.title("Add a new Exersise")
add.geometry('600x600')
add.configure(bg='grey')
add.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

ExNm = tk.Label(add, bg='grey', text="Exercise Name")
ExNm.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, sticky='nesw')

Name = tk.Entry(add)
Name.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=15, sticky='nesw')

YtLink = tk.Label(add, bg='grey', text="Youtube Link")
YtLink.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, sticky='nesw')

Link = tk.Entry(add)
Link.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=10, padx=15, sticky='nesw')

DocLink = tk.Label(add, bg='grey', text="Tab Document | e.g. Alternate Picking.pdf")
DocLink.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=10, sticky='nesw')

Tab = tk.Entry(add)
Tab.grid(row=5, column=0, pady=10, padx=15, sticky='nesw')

def sliderFunction(event):
    Beats = BPM.get()
    print(Beats)

BPM_Label = tk.Label(add, bg='grey', text="BPM")
BPM_Label.grid(row=6, column=0, pady=10, sticky='nesw')

BPM = Scale(add,from_=0, to=400, orient=HORIZONTAL, font=('Helvetica','15'))
BPM.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", sliderFunction)
BPM.grid(row=7, column=0, pady=10, padx=15, sticky='nesw')
```

Comment: I recommend reading up on sqlite, though you can probably just append data to a flat file.

Comment: well, I recommend using json files (my favourite and they are super easy at least for simple operations) but as said before a plain .txt file will do fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580527/saving-datas-from-treeview-to-csv-file-tkinter-python).

Normally you could build a treeview and store then into CSV.